# Record exists on custom record

Tags: netsuite

I had created a custom record few months back which was working fine but since the last few days have started getting ‘Record already exists’ message when I try to create a new entry. Even if I choose only the mandatory fields only (3 out of some 20 fields are mandatory) and choose a different value every time for the text fields, I still keep getting this. Anyone else faced the same issue? I do not see a mechanism to enforce unique constraint and have no idea which fields the custom record is pointing at.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom Record entries must be unique on the name field (if a name field exists) and on the internal id field. NetSuite takes care of the internal id field automatically/internally, but if your custom record type has a name field, it must also be unique and you cannot create 2 entries with the same name.

Comment: There was a custom workflow which was enabled and was throwing this error, found it now :)